# Find string in text file and print strings near it

Tags: python, search, screen-scraping

I'll try to explain my goal. I have to write reports based on a document sent to me that has common strings in it. For example, the document sent to me contains data like:

```
"reportId": 84561234,

  "dateReceived": "2020-01-19T17:54:31.000+0000",

"reportingEsp": {

      "firstName": "Google",
      "lastName": "Reviewer",
      "addresses": {
        "address": [
          {
            "street1": "1600 Ampitheater Parkway",
            "street2": null,
            "city": "Mountainview",
            "postalCode": "94043",
            "state": "CA",
            "nonUsaState": null,
            "country": "US",
            "type": "BUSINESS"
```

This is an example of the 'raw' data. It is also presented in a PDF. I have tried scraping the PDF using tabula, but there seems to be some issue with fonts?? So I only get about 10% of the text. And I am wondering/thinking going after the raw data will be more accurate/easier...(if you think scraping the PDF would be easier, please let me know)

So I used this code:

```
with open('filetobesearched.txt', 'r') as searchfile:
    for line in searchfile:
        if 'reportId' in line:
            print (line)
        if 'dateReceived' in line:
            print (line)
        if 'firstName' in line:
            print (line)
```

and this is where trouble starts... there are multiple occurrences of the string 'firstName' in the file. So my code as exists prints each of those one after the other. In the raw file those fields exist in different sections each are preceded by a section header like in the example above 'reportingESP'. So I'd like my code to somehow know the 'firstName' string belongs to a given section and the next occurrence belongs to another section to be printed with it... (make sense?)

Eventually I'd like to parse out the address information but omit any fields with a null.

And ULTIMATELY I'd like the data outputted into a file I could then in turn import into my report template and fill those fields as applicable. Which seems like a huge thing to me... so I'll be happy with help simply parsing through the raw data and outputting the results to a file in the proper order.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: The data appears to be in JSON format. Use a JSON parser to parse it into a data structure and then access the elements of that data structure. Python provides JSON support in the [`json`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#module-json) module. Once you have the data parsed it should be pretty easy to selectively write it to a file.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, yes TIL - it's json data. So I accomplished my goal like this:

JSON Data

```
"reportId": 84561234,

  "dateReceived": "2020-01-19T17:54:31.000+0000",

"reportingEsp": {

      "firstName": "Google",
      "lastName": "Reviewer",
      "addresses": {
        "address": [
          {
            "street1": "1600 Ampitheater Parkway",
            "street2": null,
            "city": "Mountainview",
            "postalCode": "94043",
            "state": "CA",
            "nonUsaState": null,
            "country": "US",
            "type": "BUSINESS"
```

My code:

```
import json

# read files
myjsonfile=open('file.json', 'r')
jsondata=myjsonfile.read()

# Parse
obj=json.loads(jsondata)

#parse through the json data to populate report variables
rptid = str(str(obj['reportId']))
dateReceived = str(str(obj['dateReceived']))

print('Report ID: ', rptid)
print('Date Received: ', dateReceived)
```

So now that I have those as variables I am trying to using them to fill a docx template... but that's another question I think.

Consider this one answered. Thanks again!